# destroy std::mutex vs pthread_mutex_t

Tags: c++, mutex, stdmutex

What is the difference between std::mutex and pthread_mutex_t in CPP?

What is the correct way to destroy each one of the mutex types when they are dynamically allocated as follows:

pthread_mutex_t * mutex1 = new pthread_mutex_t();

std::mutex * mutex2 = new std::mutex ();

Comment: the "right" way to use `std::mutex` does not use `new`.

Comment: why do you want to dynamically allocate a `std::mutex` ?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the quick respond! Each time I use my cpp file a job is created with a few threads. All the threads need to share the same mutex and it is possible to use my cpp file from different places. 

How do you suggest to do it ?

Comment: One difference is that `pthread_mutex` is Posix only, while `std::mutex` is, eh ... standard, and available elsewhere.

Comment: @BoP (one could make the opposite argument that `std::mutex` is C++-only, while `pthread_mutex` is available in all languages)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that they are from different libraries. They are both mutexes (mutices?).

`pthread_mutex` is from a library designed for C, so it does not use constructors or destructors. Simply creating a `pthread_mutex_t` object *does not create a mutex*. You have to call `pthread_mutex_init` to create the mutex. Likewise you have to call `pthread_mutex_destroy` to destroy it, because it has no destructor which does this.

`std::mutex` is designed for C++ so of course the object itself always acts as a mutex, with no need for separate function calls.

```
pthread_mutex_t * mutex1 = new pthread_mutex_t; // () not needed
// you created a pthread_mutex_t object, but didn't initialize it.
// You created it with new, so destroy it with delete:
delete mutex1;

pthread_mutex_t * mutex1 = new pthread_mutex_t; // () not needed
// you created a pthread_mutex_t object
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex1, nullptr); // can check return value for errors
// and used that space to store whatever data a mutex has in it (perhaps pthread_mutex_init allocates other memory)
// Reverse pthread_mutex_init with pthread_mutex_destroy:
pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex1); // can check return value for errors
// You created it with new, so destroy it with delete:
delete mutex1;

std::mutex * mutex3 = new std::mutex; // () not needed
// You created it with new, so destroy it with delete
delete mutex3;
```

However, you don't need to allocate everything with `new`. C++ isn't Java. If you want an object, then in the vast majority of cases you can just have one:

```
std::mutex mutex4;
// automatically destroyed when it goes out of scope
```

and the C version:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex5;
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex5, nullptr); // can check return value for errors
// Reverse pthread_mutex_init with pthread_mutex_destroy:
pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex5); // can check return value for errors
// Variable is destroyed when it goes out of scope.
// Of course you can reuse the same variable for a new mutex by calling init again
// and destroy when you are done
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation ! It really helped !